# CI on different database platforms

Tags: oracle, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I want to test my application (especially SQL statements) against different databases. Actually I'm using Cruise Control and Oracle.

I want expand the tests with other databases.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific in the problem you're facing?

Comment: I want to have an integrated solution to test my app against different databases. run unit tests against oracle, mssql, sybase etc.
Just provide some configuration for each test run. 
configuration for oracle ->Run tests against Oracle -> report.
configuration for msssql -> Run tests against mssql -> report.
......

I know I can set up 3 instances of Cruise control and have 3 different configuration, but I want to have ale the tests integrated somehow.

Comment: What kind of application is it?  How do you interact with it for testing specific functionality?

Comment: It is a .NET application. I have a set of unit tests (MBUnit) for each layer. Now, i.e for GetPersonById() method I have some sql statements that needs to be tested, I know that they will work against Oracle (already tested), but not sure about other database platforms.This needs to be testes some automatic way. Interaction is just commiting code into SVN reposytory. Then Cruise Control does everything else. The problem is that the tests are just against Oracle (because connection string in app.config). So I'm looking for a tool where I can manage how the tests are run and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our software has a .config file with database configuration. If you can separate out the configuration in any way, f.eks like we do. Then you can duplicate the cruise control test project (TestsOracle, TestsMSSql) and switch the configuration in a task before the unit test task. We test for Oracle, MySql and SQL Server like that.

I also created a plugin that retrieves the code modifications from the build task, so for each test execution we can see the code modifications built into the actual unit test execution.

Hope that helps!